# PHP "&curren" string turns into weird symbol

Tags: php, string

The following PHP code:

```
<?php
$s = "page.com?a=1&current";
echo $s;
```

outputs the unexpected:

```
page.com?a=1¤t
```

Setting the file encoding to utf-8 didn't work. When I set `$s` to "page.com?a=1&curre", the output is as expected.

I want to know if this is because in my project I have `$url`, which needs to be appended with "&currentPage=1".

What is causing this problem?

Comment: the output is ok.  the browser view &curren; :-).

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduce the problem, perhaps you should add other elements to your question.

Comment: @Eugen that's true, but if this happens when echoing a link to the page, things can get messed up.

Comment: @sidyll ah so, ok.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's the [entity code](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) for the currency symbol being interpreted. If you're building your GET url, you can solve it in various ways:

- Use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on your query values:

  `$s = 'page.com?' . urlencode("a=1&currentPage=2");`
- Use the entity for `&` itself;

  `'page.com?a=1&amp;currentPage=2'`
- Or use your variable at the beginning so no `&` is required:

  `'page.com?currentPage=2&a=1'`

Answer (score 3):

Ampersands `&` need to be converted into HTML special characters (using e.g. [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), or simply typing it in). Your output into HTML should look like this:

```
$s = "page.com?a=1&amp;current";
```

Otherwise they may collide with HTML entities, as happens in your example. The HTML entity for `¤` is `&curren;`, and for reasons unknown to me, these entities match in HTML even without the closing `;`. Edit: As to why and when this happens, keyword being historical reasons, [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689230/why-do-html-entity-names-with-dec-255-not-require-semicolon).

Comment: They are not valid, but are matched by most parsers in browsers anyway. Maybe for backwards compatibility

Comment: Yup. Just added in a link with more background on why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

problem is because of &curren is short code for ¤ sign. so whenever you put **&current** it took it as **¤t**.

to solve this you can use urlencode function

```
$s = urlencode("page.com?a=1&current");
echo $s;
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: `&curren;` is an html entity but not `&curren`

Comment: but somehow it transform it without **;**

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying the string on screen then you just need to replace all & characters with `&amp;` JUST FOR DISPLAYING ON SCREEN. Don't actually replace the characters in the url string like this else the url will not work correctly.

eg.

`printf( 'this is my string: %s' , str_replace('&', '&amp;', $yourFullString) );`

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is convert the `&` to the encode format like `&amp;`. This will work for me. Here is example

```
URL."reference=1&amp;currency=";
```