# URL from data base is not correct when i use PHP with Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have DB with Url's.
For example, my url is

```
https://besplatka.ua/?prop[161][from]=1&prop[161][to]=3&prop[136][to]=20000&currency=USD
```

When i use this PHP code

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT url FROM urls WHERE id=5");
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $my_url=$res['url'];
}
echo $my_url;
```

I see that the php page does not display the correct value. Encoding everywhere is UTF-8.

```
https://besplatka.ua/?prop[161][from]=1&prop[161][to]=3&prop[136][to]=20000¤cy=USD
```

What does this symbol ¤ mean? How do I fix the error?

Comment: Can you share your connection code?

Comment: my connection code is
<?php
$databaseHost = 'localhost';
$databaseName = 'sys';
$databaseUsername = 'root';
$databasePassword = '';
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $databaseName); 
?>

Comment: Run this right after settting the connection `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");`

Comment: Like Mr @Mihai said, add to set_charset to your connection code

Comment: I was add
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); to connection code But it's not work. The result is the same.

Comment: I`m guessing you have to insert it again,or fix it in the db.

Comment: In db all ok. php page does not display the correct value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335786/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search and try I found that the error is not about encoding UTF8 but the `&` symbol with `curren` word become this `¤`.

(To get information about symbols: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

So you can fix this by using `urlencode` function or just put your variable on the first of URL.

Result: `https://besplatka.ua/?currency=USD&prop[161][from]=1&prop[161][to]=3&prop[136][to]=20000`

I hope that can help you.

Comment: `<?php
$databaseHost = 'localhost';
$databaseName = 'sys';
$databaseUsername = 'root';
$databasePassword = '';
 $mysqli = mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $databaseName);
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");
?>`
not work. The result is the same.

Comment: That your DB has the UTF8 type?

Comment: You can check this comment: [#14068747 - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14068747/6173086)

Comment: utf8_general_ci in db.

Comment: i have this header
`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`
but But it's not work. The result is with ¤

Comment: thans very mutch

Comment: @user2219963 you're welcome. If the answer helps you don't forget to mark it correct to help other people.