# PHP Function Generating Invalid HMAC Signature

Tags: php, urlencode, hmac

I'm working on integrating MoonPay with my website but there is something I can't figure out.
Their default PHP code posted here: https://dev.moonpay.com/docs/ramps-sdk-url-signing#how-to-generate-signatures

```
$host = 'https://buy-sandbox.moonpay.com';
$query = '?apiKey=pk_test_key&currencyCode=eth&walletAddress=0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae';

$signature  = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $query, 'sk_test_key', true));

echo $host . $query . "&signature=" . urlencode($signature);
```

When I test this default code on my server it produce invalid signature also the generated URL contains some weird characters like this

```
¤
```

So for example a code like this

```
<?php
$host = 'https://buy.moonpay.com'; // Use the live endpoint
$query = '?apiKey=pk_live_000000000000000000000&currencyCode=eth&walletAddress=0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae';

$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $query, 'sk_live_00000000000000000000000000', true));

echo $host . $query . "&signature=" . urlencode($signature);
?>
```

Generate a url like this with invalid signature:

```
https://buy.moonpay.com?apiKey=pk_live_00000000000¤cyCode=eth&walletAddress=0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae&signature=kPp00000000000000000000%3D
```

I've replaced my keys with zeros as I don't want to post my live keys here.

My server is LAMP Ubuntu running Wordpress/WooCommerce I can't figure out if the problem in their example code or my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is &curren is entity code for the currency symbol in php.

You can build your solution like below:

```
<?php
$host = 'https://buy-sandbox.moonpay.com';
$query = urlencode('?apiKey=pk_test_key&currencyCode=eth&walletAddress=0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae');

$signature  = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $query, 'sk_test_key', true));

echo $host . $query . urlencode("&signature=") . urlencode($signature);
```

Please refer to answer in previously asked question at [PHP "&curren" string turns into weird symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335786/php-curren-string-turns-into-weird-symbol)

Comment: Thank you for precisely determining the issue.
The problem now and correct me if I'm wrong is that MoonPay requires only the values to be encoded not the entire string so the signature is still invalid.

Requirements:
Compute an HMAC with a SHA-256 hash function. Use your secret API key as the key, and use the original query string as the message.

All query parameter values including the signature (not the entire query string) need to be URL encoded before generating the signature in order for it to be valid.