# Are There Downsides to Writing `&lt` Instead of `&lt;`

Tags: html, escaping, special-characters

I recently learned that in HTML one can leave off the semi-colon in character entities (eg. `&lt` to create a `<` character, instead of `&lt;`).

I found some really old Stack Overflow posts that mentioned that really old browsers (eg. IE7) might have problems with such character entities.  However, I haven't been able to find, either on the web or just by testing, any problems with such character entities in modern browsers.

So is there any reason at all not to use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is entirely up to how forgiving the browser/rendering engine wants to be, and is not a property of HTML. All entities must end in a semi-colon, or you have invalid syntax. The WHATWG "HTML Living Standard" confusingly considers this semi-colon to be part of the name, making it seem optional in the Developer Edition. But the full Standard text/W3C HTML5 draft is clearer: "The name must be one that is terminated by a U+003B **SEMICOLON** character (;)."

Historically the semicolon has been optional when a character entity is not immediately followed by a name character. For example, `&pound?` will work because `?` is not a name character (i.e., a character allowed in names), but `&pound4` will not because 4 is a name character, making `pound4` the entity name which is undefined. This rule is part of SGML legacy in HTML, one of the few things where browsers actually applied specialties of SGML.

That being said, it has always been regarded as good practice to terminate entity references by a semicolon. XML, and hence XHTML, makes it mandatory.

This is why current browser practices allow omission of semicolons as in “classic” HTML, but only for the limited set of character references denoting ISO Latin 1 characters (characters with Unicode number less than 256 in decimal or FF in hexadecimal). This was the original set of entity references, and therefore such references have widely been used without semicolon. So the practices are a compromise: they want to encourage using the specified notation but not invalidate a bulk of old pages that don't conform and make browsers fail to render them properly.

The HTML5 drafts have had various positions on this, but HTML5 requires the semicolon in all cases even in HTML syntax. Lack of semicolon is defined as a parse error, which means that error handling is well-defined (the entity shall be recognized), but browsers may still stop parsing at first parse error.

According to the [W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/charset.html#entities)

> In SGML, it is possible to eliminate the final ";" after a character reference in some cases (e.g., at a line break or immediately before a tag). In other circumstances it may not be eliminated (e.g., in the middle of a word). We strongly suggest using the ";" in all cases to avoid problems with user agents that require this character to be present.

While the [W3C Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/syntax.html#character-references) states

> The ampersand must be followed by one of the names given in §8.5 Named character references section, using the same case. The name must be one that is terminated by a U+003B SEMICOLON character (;).

Because the semicolon is required for W3C validation, and because it works in all browsers you should use it. The absolutely minuscule amount of page size you will save by not using them is not worth the risk of them not displaying right in all browsers.

Here are two answers to similar questions about this topic:
[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18689444/9318764)
[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18692507/9318764)

Comment: Thanks. So is the only reason because of a validator, or is there any actual *real* reason not to?

Comment: @machineghost The biggest reason I would say to use them is due to the universal support for including them. We know that if you include them any browser will display them how you intended them to be seen. Whereas if you don't use them--since there is no universal spec/support yet for not including them at the end of the entity--there is no guarantee that it will display properly and there is no sense in messing up your design over one character in the markup.

Comment: Also, while Google doesn't factor W3C Validation into search engine rankings, a clean code does help the search engine spiders read and understand your website easier. A clean coded website will guide the spider to the important places on your site, without getting jumbled up in a web of unnecessary coding.

Comment: [Let's use the current standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/syntax.html#character-references) and not an old draft.

Comment: @machineghost The biggest reason is because it's the standard and the standard is written and approved by browser vendors who follow that same standard when they write their browser code. It is required that browsers do the best they can with broken markup but do you want your broken, non-standard markup to be guessed at by a browser?

Comment: @Rob You are absolutely right. I didn't notice that I didn't pull up the most current standard when I posted that. I just edited the link and answer to reflect that. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks all for the responses.  The thing is, I'm asking this for a class and don't feel comfortable telling a student "if you leave semicolons out the big, bad (and non-existent) standards enforcer will get you!"  If every major browser supports something, that something *is* the standard, regardless of what the W3C or any other body says, and this has been proven time and time again throughout the web's history.  So it really sounds like the *honest* answer is "leaving off semicolons won't hurt anything in the real world, except validators and feelings (of people who like the W3C standards)."

Comment: @machineghost No problem. I noticed this morning that I didn't do a great job of answering your question as I only really addressed why you should use them. I didn't specifically address any downsides other than browsers not displaying the characters 100% of the time. I have found the following 2 answers which might be what you are looking for. [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18692507/9318764), [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18689444/9318764)

Comment: Thank you @Angeliss44, those links were much more what I was looking for.  If you'd care to incorporate the information from those answers, either into a new answer or as an edited version of your current answer, I'll happily accept it.  Alternatively if you want to flag this as a duplicate of that question (they're slightly different questions, but one could argue they're close enough to be duplicates) I'll happily second that flag.  Whichever you prefer.

Comment: You're welcome @machineghost. As the questions are slightly different I have edited my answer above to include this additional information.

Comment: @Angeliss44 Your W3C link goes to the the outdated HTML4 spec from 1999. The link to W3C's current HTML 5.2 spec (section on named character entities) is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#named-character-references. As W3C mostly just copy and slightly edit WHATWG's spec text, the listed named character entity references includes semicolon characters as well. As to your general remark on SGML, I can assure you that HTML, including HTML5, uses many SGML features such as tag inference (see my paper at http://sgmljs.net/docs/html5.html for details).