# Using lxml.html with broken html entities?

Tags: python, html, html-entities, lxml.html

I need to work with a page, which has an unfortunate mix of correct and incorrect HTML entities; for instance:

```
<i>Kristj&aacuten V&iacute;ctor</i>
```

This, in Firefox 67, does get interpreted correctly, eventually:

[image: ff-htmlent1.png]

... however, if we do "View Source", Firefox indicates via syntax color that something is wrong with the first HTML entity:

[image: ff-htmlent2.png]

... and indeed there is, a semicolon at the end of the HTML entity is missing - however, somehow Firefox figures it out, and renders the right character.

Now, if I try to work with that in lxml:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import lxml.html as LH
import lxml.html.clean as LHclean

testhtmlstring = "<i>Kristj&aacuten V&iacute;ctor</i>"

myhtml = LH.fromstring( testhtmlstring )
myhtml = LHclean.clean_html( myhtml )
myitem = myhtml.xpath("//i")[0]
myitemstr = myitem.text_content()
print(myitemstr)
```

... the code prints out this in terminal (Ubuntu 18.04):

```
Kristj&aacuten Víctor
```

... so, obviously, the broken htmlentity did not get converted to the right character.

Is there something I can use, so I get the right character in my output string from lxml, even in case of a broken htmlentity (as Firefox does)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML 5 standard has specified a specific subset of entities that can be parsed without the trailing semicolon present, because [these entities were historically defined with the semicolon being optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689230/why-do-html-entity-names-with-dec-255-not-require-semicolon).

The [`html.unescape()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) explicitly supports those, use that function as a second pass to clear out this issue:

```
>>> from html import unescape
>>> unescape("Kristj&aacuten Víctor")
'Kristján Víctor'
```

If you install [`html5lib`](https://pypi.org/project/html5lib/) then you can have lxml behave the same, via their [`lxml.html.html5parser` module](https://lxml.de/html5parser.html) (which wraps `html5lib`'s own [`html5lib.treebuilders.etree_lxml` adapter](https://html5lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/html5lib.treebuilders.html#module-html5lib.treebuilders.etree_lxml)):

```
>>> from lxml.html import html5parser as etree
>>> etree.fromstring("Kristj&aacuten Víctor").text
'Kristján Víctor'
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, great help - had no idea that there is a subset of htmlentities allowed with a semicolon.